# sql server join 2 datasets with no condition

Tags: sql-server

I have t datasets from 2 different queries.

Query 1 outputs :

```
ProductId
1
```

Query 2 Outputs

```
Name
ABC
DEF
GHI
KLM
```

I want to get a result something like :

```
ProductId Name
1  ABC
1  DEF
1  GHI
1  KLM
```

I cannot join since I don't have any common column. I cannot do unions as it is giving me nulls that I don't want . Any ideas on how I can achieve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT ProductId, Name
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
```

The output is the cartesian product between rows of `table1` and `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Query1
(
    ProductId INT
)

INSERT INTO #Query1 VALUES(1)

CREATE TABLE #Query2 
(
    Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Query2 VALUES
 ('ABC')
,('DEF')
,('GHI')
,('KLM')


SELECT * 
FROM
#Query1 Q1 CROSS JOIN #Query2
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.